# Access to the path 'c:\\log.txt' is denied in File.Create

Tags: c#, access-denied

I am trying to create a log file in my program:

```
if (!File.Exists("c://log.txt"))
{
    File.Create("c://log.txt");
}
```

I have received this error:

> Access to the path 'c:\log.txt' is denied

How can i get access to c ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating system? Windows 7 or windows 8? And what user starts the program a normal one or one with administrator rights?

Comment: If the call to `Exists` or `Create` failing. It looks like permissions are coming into play.

Comment: I am using Windows 8. The current user have administrator rights.

Comment: How can i ask the user for administrator rights?

Comment: Some paths are not writable in Windows for normal users. The only path that always is writable, even as a guest, is the user directory, and of course %temp%. With every other path you have to check whether you have permissions - either explicitly, or by try{create}catch{createInUserDirectory}. What I wouldn't even think of is force the user to give additional permissions just because you want to write a logfile...

Comment: at all, the `C` drive and this main path, is not suitable for writing, choice another path (if you can)

Comment: Do you also run your VisualStudio as admin? You have to explicitly run it as admin to get admin-rights, no matter, if your current user is admin or not.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - exactly - RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have to force .NET to run this programm as administrator:

[How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

But you should write your log file any where else then "C:\", you can use a temp directory like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.path.gettemppath(v=vs.110).aspx or you use something like "C:\temp"

If you like to write your log file into the directory of the executing assembly use this to get the directory:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: Q: My door won't open when I push the handle, help? A: Use a crowbar to break in. -- This might or might not be a good solution, depending on context (to keep the analogy, great idea if the house is on fire).

Comment: That's true. Therefore i said that he should not write a log file to "C:\".

Comment: It did run when used as an administrator